# Hiding game resources

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm creating a 2D opengl es android game.When someone extract an apk with winrar he can see all of the resources.So he can clone my game.Is there a way for hiding these resources?

Comment: Generally speaking -- if anyone clones your game that way, you have a strong copyright infringement case against them, and (in the US, at least) can collect 3x their income in damages. I'd be less worried about direct ripoffs than about folks copying the concept and building their own assets for a similar game -- it's that latter kind of cloning that's a higher risk. Anyhow, protecting them from being unpacked from the APK doesn't protect them from being captured through screenshots of the emulator or other approaches; it's a very low barrier.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible :  you can convert your images to raw data and embed that data directly in your source code. Example : with GIMP -> save as -> .c source file or .h header.
But this will increase the size of your executable.

Comment: You can also embed a JPEG or other compressed file in a byte array, and thus get the same kind of "protection" without losing compression (as happens when just saving as a raw byte array here).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I agree with our first comment but I think this is allready a first good barrier. it is so easy to unzip an APK and have the whole source code (with dex 2 jar) and assets. The real protection would be to have the game in c or c++, not in java, so that nobody can have a look at the source code.

Comment: Assets, I grant you, but there's a huge difference between decompiled source and "real" source in terms of maintainability. I'd much, much rather have a competitor who decompiled my jars than one who built their own, because the former one will (1) have a much harder time trying to add features or fix bugs, and (2) be easy to sue and take their assets if they actually make any money.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for comments.I have saw that rovio is using dat files in angry birds.What about that?

Comment: @Philippe Thanks for comments.I have saw that rovio is using dat files in angry birds.What about that?

Comment: @droidmachine That's funny I also checked how they did. They use .dat files and also .pngs, form what I've seen, the .dat file only tells what the png corresponds to.